# VueJS - how component gets global data item?

Tags: vue.js

I have code like this :

```
Vue.component("sample", {
    inherit: true,
    template: "#sample",
    props: {
       active : "active",
       ...
    },
    methods: {
      forceChangeActive: function(){
         var activeItem = this.$parent._data.active;
         var modalSetup = this.$parent._data.showModal;
         console.log("1.before function", this.$parent._data);
         this.$parent.$options.methods.baseAction(activeItem, modalSetup);
         console.log("2.before function", this.$parent._data);
      });
    }
});
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        active: 0,
        showModal: false,
        ...
    }, 
    methods: {
        baseAction: function(activeItem, modalSetup){
            console.log("3.modal", modalSetup, "activeItem": activeItem);
            modalSetup = true;
            activeItem = 2;
            console.log("4.modal", modalSetup, "activeItem": activeItem);
        }
    }
});
```

There are active and showModal data variables in new Vue. Now I'm getting undefined for both if I use this.active or this.showModal. 
And console output is:

> 1. before function  Object { active=0,  showModal=false }
> 2. modal false, activeItem 0
> 3. modal true, activeItem 2
> 4. before function  Object { active=0,  showModal=false }

How I can change variable`s values in new Vue or in component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inherit:true` is deprecated.

You need to explicitly pass `active` and `showModal` to the child component using properties.  You can use `.sync` to make sure they are shared back to the parent as well:

```
<sample :active.sync="active" :show-modal.sync="showModal"></sample>
```